# How to find the socket buffer size of linux

Tags: linux, sockets, buffer

What's the default socket buffer size of linux? Is there any command to see it?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

If you want see your buffer size in terminal, you can take a look at:

- `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem` (for read)
- `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem` (for write)

They contain three numbers, which are minimum, default and maximum memory size values (in byte), respectively.

Comment: There is also `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default` for recv and `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default` for send, as referenced http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html

Comment: I found more detailed descriptions for these inside `man 7 tcp` and `man 7 udp`.

Comment: @VladimírČunát, and see `man 7 socket` and search for `proc interfaces` too.

Answer (score 43):

For getting the buffer size in c/c++ program the following is the flow

```c
int n;
unsigned int m = sizeof(n);
int fdsocket;
fdsocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP); // example
getsockopt(fdsocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVBUF,(void *)&n, &m);
// now the variable n will have the socket size
```

Comment: Is it safe to call `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)` instead? I'm using this C call in my Swift TCP framework to get the buffer size to reduce `recv` calls.

Comment: Note: this is also only the read buffer size, use SO_SNDBUF to get the size of the write buffer.  Under at least linux, you can use ioctl SIOCINQ and SIOCOUTQ, to respectfully get the current used state of the buffer.

Answer (score 30):

Whilst, as has been pointed out, it is possible to see the current *default* socket buffer sizes in `/proc`, it is also possible to check them using `sysctl` (Note: Whilst the name includes ipv4 these sizes also apply to ipv6 sockets - the ipv6 tcp_v6_init_sock() code just calls the ipv4 tcp_init_sock() function):

```
 sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_rmem
 sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_wmem
```

However, the default socket buffers are just set when the sock is initialised but the kernel then dynamically sizes them (unless set using setsockopt() with `SO_SNDBUF` scoekt option). The actual size of the buffers for currently open sockets may be inspected using the `ss` command (part of the `iproute`/`iproute2` package), which can also provide a bunch more info on sockets like congestion control parameter etc. E.g. To list the currently open TCP (`t` option) sockets and associated memory (`m`) information:

```
ss -tm
```

Here's some example output:

```
State       Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port
ESTAB       0      0             192.168.56.102:ssh        192.168.56.1:56328
skmem:(r0,rb369280,t0,tb87040,f0,w0,o0,bl0,d0)
```

The [ss man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) now shows the definitions of the various `skmem` (socket memory) info returned.

> ```
> skmem:(r<rmem_alloc>,rb<rcv_buf>,t<wmem_alloc>,tb<snd_buf>,
>    f<fwd_alloc>,w<wmem_queued>,o<opt_mem>,bl<back_log>,d<sock_drop>)
>
>   <rmem_alloc>
>          the memory allocated for receiving packet
>
>   <rcv_buf>
>          the total memory can be allocated for receiving
>          packet
>
>   <wmem_alloc>
>          the memory used for sending packet (which has been
>          sent to layer 3)
>
>   <snd_buf>
>          the total memory can be allocated for sending
>          packet
>
>   <fwd_alloc>
>          the memory allocated by the socket as cache, but
>          not used for receiving/sending packet yet. If need
>          memory to send/receive packet, the memory in this
>          cache will be used before allocate additional
>          memory.
>
>   <wmem_queued>
>          The memory allocated for sending packet (which has
>          not been sent to layer 3)
>
>   <opt_mem>
>          The memory used for storing socket option, e.g.,
>          the key for TCP MD5 signature
>
>   <back_log>
>          The memory used for the sk backlog queue. On a
>          process context, if the process is receiving
>          packet, and a new packet is received, it will be
>          put into the sk backlog queue, so it can be
>          received by the process immediately
>
>   <sock_drop>
>          the number of packets dropped before they are de-
>          multiplexed into the socket
> ```

This info comes from the kernel - here's a brief explanation of the relevant skmem variables - for more details take a look at the kernel sources (i.e. [sock.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/net/sock.h)):

> ```
> r:sk_rmem_alloc
> rb:sk_rcvbuf          # current receive buffer size
> t:sk_wmem_alloc
> tb:sk_sndbuf          # current transmit buffer size
> f:sk_forward_alloc    # space allocated forward
> w:sk_wmem_queued      # persistent transmit queue size
> o:sk_omem_alloc
> bl:sk_backlog
> d:sk_drops
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I'm still trying to piece together the details, but to add to the answers already given, these are some of the important commands:

```bash
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/udp_mem
cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem
ss -m  # see `man ss`
```

References & help pages:

1. Man pages

   ```bash
   man 7 socket
   man 7 udp
   man 7 tcp
   man ss
   ```
2. https://www.linux.org/threads/how-to-calculate-tcp-socket-memory-usage.32059/

Answer (score -7):

Atomic size is 4096 bytes, max size is 65536 bytes. Sendfile uses 16 pipes each of 4096 bytes size.
cmd : ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &buff_size).

Comment: What does 'atomic size' mean; what does `sendfile()` have to do with it; and where have you answered the question about the default socket buffer size?

Comment: @ EJP Atomic size  - Linux internals assert for 4096b socket transfer - MT-safe, mutex, 1/16 internal pipes. sandfile has a lot to do with it. I think i have. Default buffer size is 16*4096b.

Comment: None of this answers the question. It is about socket send and receive buffer sizes. Not about `sendfile()`, which therefore has *nothing* to do with it, nor atomic transfer sizes either, ditto.