# Do sockets automatically read into internal buffer

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

Let's say a `Server` sends a small amount of data, but a `Client` never calls `recv()`, will the data sent by the `Server` be present in an internal receive buffer on the `Client` side even though `read()`, `recv()`, ... were never called?

Comment: yes. the entire concept of TCP Window Size is based on that. It happens in UDP as well, try it!

Comment: @Yarin_007, is there any way to get how full the internal buffer is, without actually reading it?

Comment: On linux it seems to be [pretty easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56279407/4935162), for TCP. In windows (or linux...) i *guess* you could spin up wireshark and look at the (calculated) window size there, on, say, the first packet your process sends after the # way handshake.  (i say calculated because in the TCP  handshake the 2 sides agree on a multiplication - scaling factor. wireshark parses it and displays it.)

Comment: Knowing how full the internal buffer is, is less helpful than you might imagine, since the number reported to you might already be out-of-date by the time you act on it.  (e.g. between the time the value is returned and the time you examine it, more data might have been received from the network and added to the buffer)

Comment: @err69 on 'Nix systems, you can use `ioctl(FIONREAD)`, on Windows you can use `ioctlsocket(FIONREAD)`.